# What's is the difference between app-header and paper-header-panel?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

What's the diference between app-header and paper-header-panel, that is the same question for app-toolbar and paper-toolbar, is about Polymer version? Cause I was following [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/app-layout#condensing-header) tutorial, but I'n trying to build a Condensing header with sticky paper-tabs on top with the currents Polimer Elements(paper-header-panel, paper-toolbar), and I can't get the exactly sticky paper-tab like the example.

Thanks for your time, I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polymer catalog is divided into a couple different categories enabling greater choice and control for developers.

[App elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=app-elements) enable building full web apps out of modular custom elements

[Paper elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements) are a set of visual elements that implement Google's Material Design.

There is overlap between some App elements and Paper elements; and in many cases, Paper elements build on top of App elements.

The primary difference is that App elements are unstyled where Paper elements are styled to meet the [Google Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/).

Comment: That help me a lot, Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

[image: ChromeDev Summit image]

as stated in this [video](https://youtu.be/g7f1Az5fxgU?t=5m38s) from the chrome dev summit .. the app-header is more app-like and the address bar disappears as the user scrolls up.

Comment: In which second off the video they say that?, 'cause I watched it but I don't hear nothing about it

Comment: hey @JuanSalcedo sorry.. the right video is in [this link](https://youtu.be/g7f1Az5fxgU?t=5m38s)  .. in the minute 5:37. i updated my answer